# Go lang func parameter type

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to find func parameter type and its name to generate some code. 
I am using `ast` package for it.
I've found parameter name, but I can't find parameter type name.

```
for _, fun := range findFunc(node) { //ast.FuncDecl

    if  fun.Recv != nil {
        for _, field := range fun.Type.Params.List {
            for _, name := range field.Names {
                println(name.Name)  //Func field name
                //How to find field type name here?
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, `FuncType.Params` is the (incoming) parameter list of the function. Its `List` field holds all the parameters, which are of type [`ast.Field`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Field):

```
type Field struct {
        Doc     *CommentGroup // associated documentation; or nil
        Names   []*Ident      // field/method/parameter names; or nil if anonymous field
        Type    Expr          // field/method/parameter type
        Tag     *BasicLit     // field tag; or nil
        Comment *CommentGroup // line comments; or nil
}
```

The `Field.Type` holds the type of the parameter which is an interface type [`ast.Expr`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Expr) with simply embeds the [`ast.Node`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Node) which only provides you the start and end position of the type in the source. Basically this should be enough to get the text representation of the type.

Let's see a simple example. We will analyze this function:

```
func myfunc(i int, s string, err error, pt image.Point, x []float64) {}
```

And the code to print its parameters, including type names:

```
src := `package xx
func myfunc(i int, s string, err error, pt image.Point, x []float64) {}`

fset := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "src.go", src, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
offset := f.Pos()

ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
    if fd, ok := n.(*ast.FuncDecl); ok {
        fmt.Printf("Function: %s, parameters:\n", fd.Name)
        for _, param := range fd.Type.Params.List {
            fmt.Printf("  Name: %s\n", param.Names[0])
            fmt.Printf("    ast type          : %T\n", param.Type)
            fmt.Printf("    type desc         : %+v\n", param.Type)
            fmt.Printf("    type name from src: %s\n",
                src[param.Type.Pos()-offset:param.Type.End()-offset])
        }
    }
    return true
})
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IgUkPRJwb5l)):

```
Function: myfunc, parameters:
  Name: i
    ast type          : *ast.Ident
    type desc         : int
    type name from src: int
  Name: s
    ast type          : *ast.Ident
    type desc         : string
    type name from src: string
  Name: err
    ast type          : *ast.Ident
    type desc         : error
    type name from src: error
  Name: pt
    ast type          : *ast.SelectorExpr
    type desc         : &{X:image Sel:Point}
    type name from src: image.Point
  Name: x
    ast type          : *ast.ArrayType
    type desc         : &{Lbrack:71 Len:<nil> Elt:float64}
    type name from src: []float64
```